# How to translate the image to center of the screen even the image from any position?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2, translate-animation

What I wanted is the image 1 can move around on the screen, after the user touch or click the image 1, the image 1 translate to the center of the screen as image 2 whatever the image 1 is at different position. So the image 2 is in fixed position at center.

The Picture below :

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this Android documentation https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html#drag

Comment: @VishnuSP I can drag the image with no issue, I wanted is after click or touch image 1, it will translate to middle